# Why does python -c "..." load different dateutil than python file.py

Tags: python

Why would this work:

```
$ python -c "import dateutil; print dateutil.__version__"
2.6.0
```

but this would fail on, test.py:

```
import dateutil; print dateutil.__version__
```

when run as

```
$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py ", line 3, in <module>
    import dateutil; print dateutil.__version__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

The same python interpreter, same bash session and environment is used for both:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce; both versions print `1.5` for me.  Does your `test.py` happen to be in the same directory as a `dateutil.py`?

Comment: No.. but it gave me an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had a dateutil.py file in the same directory. :-(

And . in my PYTHONPATH :-(  :-(